# How to format time durations in Groovy?

Tags: parsing, time, groovy, format

I need to show time elapsed. I have the dates in following format.

```
Date1 = Thu May 23 10:10:10 EDT 2013
Date2 = Tue May 21 10:10:10 EDT 2013
```

I currently did `TimeDuration duration=TimeCategory.minus(now,LaunchTime)`

And my output shows something like `2 days, 23 minutes, 25.154 seconds`

What I want to show instead of `2 days, 23 minutes, 25.154 seconds` is something like `48:23:25`(in hours and minutes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this to create a new TimeDuration with the days turned into hours:

```
import groovy.time.TimeDuration
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

date1 = Date.parseToStringDate( 'Thu May 23 10:10:10 EDT 2013' )
date2 = Date.parseToStringDate( 'Tue May 21 12:14:10 EDT 2013' )

// Normalize method to return a new TimeDuration
TimeDuration normalize( TimeDuration tc ) {
  new TimeDuration( ( tc.days != 0 ? tc.days * 24 : 0 ) + tc.hours,
                    tc.minutes, tc.seconds, tc.millis )
}

// Then use the category to subtract the dates, and call normalize
TimeDuration normalized = use( groovy.time.TimeCategory ) {
  normalize( date1 - date2 )
}

println normalized
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I am getting close